# Algebraic independence with a first order fornula

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory

Is it possible to express the algebraic indipendence of a finite number of elements with a first order language?

Comment: Can you define "algebraic independence"?

Comment: SureLet $K$ a field. Let $F$ a field extension of $K$. Let $s_1,..,s_t$ elements of $F$. We say that  $s_1,..,s_t$  are algebraic independent over  $K$ if $p(s_1,...,s_t)\neq0$  for all $p(x_1,..,x_t)\neq0$ in $K[x_1,...,x_t]$

Comment: Thanks, and welcome to Math StackExchange. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) is some advice for asking a good question. I think the question is still impossible to answer without more context. When you say "express", do you mean that you want a first-order formula $\varphi(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ such that $F\models \varphi(s_1,\dots,s_n)$ if and only if $s_1,\dots,s_n$ are algebraically independent over $K$? A set of formulas? Are you working in the language of rings?

Comment: From the question as written, it's not even clear that you're talking about fields. "Algebraic independence" also has a model-theoretic meaning in models of a general first-order theory.